# Reac-Native: hexagon with border

Tags: javascript, react-native

in my react native app I want to have a bordered hexagon, I'm trying to achive this by having two hexagons one before the other, however for the bigger hexagon(2) I can't seem to get the proper dimensions, I got the first hexagon from a post in this blessed site, can anyone help me?

```
<View style={{width:125,height:125,position:'relative',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <View style={styles.hexagon2}>
                            <View style={styles.hexagonInner2}>
                                <View style={styles.hexagonBefore2}></View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.hexagonAfter2}></View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{width:125,height:125,position:'absolute',top:0,left:0,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                            <View style={styles.hexagon}>
                                <View style={styles.hexagonInner}>
                                    <View style={styles.hexagonBefore}></View>
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.hexagonAfter}></View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```

Hexagon styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//this one is the small hexagon, no need to touch this one
  hexagon: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55
  },
  hexagonInner: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(1,121,111)'
  },
  hexagonAfter: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 25,
    borderTopColor: 'rgb(1,121,111)'
  },
  hexagonBefore: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: 25,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgb(1,121,111)'

  },

//This ine is the bigger hexagon, the border
  hexagon2: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55,
    
  },
  hexagonInner2: {
    width: 100,
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(1,121,111)',
    
  },
  hexagonAfter2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopWidth: 25,
    borderTopColor: 'red'
  },
  hexagonBefore2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -25,
    left: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: 25,
    borderBottomColor: 'red'

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the library `react-native-svg` which lets you make complicated shapes. Example I made here (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/blissful-coffee)
and code below.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Svg, { Polygon } from 'react-native-svg';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const Hexagon = () =>{
  return (
  
        <Svg height="300" width="300" >
                <Polygon
                  points="00,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20 300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20 300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150,                     75 20 225,20"
                  fill="lime"
                  stroke="lime"
                  strokeWidth="1"
                
                >
                </Polygon>
              </Svg>
  )
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
         
           <Hexagon />
    
    
    </View>
  );
}
```